# How to colour navigation bar without styling all lists?

Tags: html, css

I've recently started learning HTML, JavaScript and CSS and was creating my own webpage. I created a navigation bar on the top of the page and styled it using CSS. I then created another list later on but when looking on the page, the CSS had styled all of the lists on the page, rather than just the navigation bar. Is there a way to style one but not all? My code is below.

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #008080;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Great Pyramid of Giza</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="Seven Wonders.html">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="Great Pyramid of Giza.html">The Great Pyramid of Giza (Honoray)</a></li>
  <li><a href="Great Wall of China.html">The Great Wall of China</a></li>
  <li><a href="Petra.html">Petra</a></li>
  <li><a href="The Colosseum.html">The Colosseum</a></li>
  <li><a href="Chichen Itza.html">Chichen Itza</a></li>
  <li><a href="Machu Pichu.html">Machu Picchu</a></li>
  <li><a href="Taj Mahal.html">Taj Mahal</a></li>
  <li><a href="Christ the Redeemer.html">Christ the Redeemer</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>What is it?</h2>
<p>The Great Pyramid of Giza is the oldest and largest of the three Pyramids in the Giza, in Egypt. It largely still remains intact.</p>
<h2>Some Facts</h2>
<ul>
  <li>It stands at 139 metres tall.
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to add a class or id to the list and target that with css, but really you should read a very very basic beginner html/css tutorial first - this is one of the first things you learn. Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) to the `ul`, and style only lists that have that `class`. Then you can move any styling that should only apply to that `class`, in to that `class`'s css entry. You can do the same thing with list items. You can use class names the same way you use the element names. You can also do this the element `id`'s.

**.html**

```
<ul class="nav-bar-list">
    <li class="nav-bar-list-item">...</li>
</ul>
```

**.css**

```
.nav-bar-list {
    background-color: #333;
}

.nav-bar-list-item {
    float: left;
}

.nav-bar-list-item a {
    // any other css you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware that you could add a class into the <ul> tag. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://codepen.io/Hjorth/pen/wjwQNX)

I just created a class for your nav

```
.mainnav
```

And defined what needs to be styled in that class